# How to create a MongoDB replica set of one node and initialize it using docker_compose.yml

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, replicaset

I am trying to use docker compose to create a MongoDB cluster with MongoDB and mongo-express. I can create the cluster just fine, but I need a single node replica set in order to enable change streams for my application. The goal is for docker compose to automatically create the replica set without the need to enter the mongo shell after running the cluster.

I've been struggling to find a working example of this. The best that I've found is [here](https://zgadzaj.com/development/docker/docker-compose/turning-standalone-mongodb-server-into-a-replica-set-with-docker-compose), but it is not working for me. The mongo container is failing to start.

This is my docker_compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=rootuser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/mongodb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
      - ./.docker/mongodb/initdb.d/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - ./.docker/mongodb/data/db/:/data/db/
      - ./.docker/mongodb/data/log/:/var/log/mongodb/
    healthcheck:
        test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate().ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo -u $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME} -p $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD} --quiet) -eq 1
        interval: 10s
        start_period: 30s
    command: ["/usr/bin/mongod -f", "/etc/mongod.conf", "--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all"]

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=rootuser
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=rootpass
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb

networks:
  default:
    name: mongo-express-network

volumes:
  mongodb-data:
    driver: local
```

The magic is supposed to be in the `command` per the post linked above, but it's just not working any way I've tried it. If I remove that, I get a working cluster of mongo and mongo-express. But no replica set.

By the way, if I enter the shell and run:

```
# mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all
Error opening config file: Is a directory
try 'mongod --help' for more information
#
```

Is `mongod.conf` located somewhere else?

Any assistance on getting this working would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir initdb.d 
echo 'rs.initiate()' |tee initdb.d/rs.js
docker run -itv `pwd`/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro -p 27017:27017 mongo --replSet myrs --bind_ip_all
```

> Is mongod.conf located somewhere else?

There isn't one on the image, so if you created it, it'll be wherever you put it.

Comment: How is this accomplished with the docker_compose.yml file?